# Can't get html5 Canvas signature pad to submit to database

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax

So I've been looking for weeks for a signature capture script that actually works and will save the signature to MySQL and I've finally found what I want but there are 2 problems.

1. I can't figure out why the canvas wont clear the signature when the clear button is pressed.
2. It wont submit the image to MySQL when the save signature button is pressed.

This code is pretty old and I've tried to contact the developer but haven't gotten a response back so I'm hoping I can get some help here.

Here is the html:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title>Signature Pad</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <center>
        <fieldset style="width: 435px">
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <div id="signaturePad" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; height: 55px; width: 400px;"></div>
            <br/>
            <button id="clearSig" type="button">Clear Signature</button>&nbsp;
            <button id="saveSig" type="button">Save Signature</button>
            <div id="imgData"></div>
            <div id="imgData"></div>
            <br/>
            <br/>
        </fieldset>
    </center>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And the remaining php and scripts:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    /** Set Canvas Size **/
    var canvasWidth = 400;
    var canvasHeight = 75;

    /** IE SUPPORT **/
    var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('signaturePad');
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.setAttribute('width', canvasWidth);
    canvas.setAttribute('height', canvasHeight);
    canvas.setAttribute('id', 'canvas');
    canvasDiv.appendChild(canvas);
    if (typeof G_vmlCanvasManager != 'undefined') {
        canvas = G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(canvas);
    }
    context = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var clickX = new Array();
    var clickY = new Array();
    var clickDrag = new Array();
    var paint;

    /** Redraw the Canvas **/
    function redraw() {
        canvas.width = canvas.width; // Clears the canvas

        context.strokeStyle = "#000000";
        context.lineJoin = "miter";
        context.lineWidth = 2;

        for (var i = 0; i < clickX.length; i++) {
            context.beginPath();
            if (clickDrag[i] && i) {
                context.moveTo(clickX[i - 1], clickY[i - 1]);
            } else {
                context.moveTo(clickX[i] - 1, clickY[i]);
            }
            context.lineTo(clickX[i], clickY[i]);
            context.closePath();
            context.stroke();
        }
    }

    /** Save Canvas **/
    $("#saveSig").click(function saveSig() {
        var sigData = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        $("#imgData").html('Thank you! Your signature was saved');
        var ajax = XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open("POST", 'http://www.your-domain.com/folder/post-html.php');
        ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/upload');
        ajax.send(sigData);
    });

    /** Clear Canvas **/
    function clearSig() {
        clickX = new Array();
        clickY = new Array();
        clickDrag = new Array();
        canvas.width = canvas.width;
        canvas.height = canvas.height;
    }

    /**Draw when moving over Canvas **/
    $('#signaturePad').mousemove(function (e) {
        if (paint) {
            addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop, true);
            redraw();
        }
    });

    /**Stop Drawing on Mouseup **/
    $('#signaturePad').mouseup(function (e) {
        paint = false;
    });

    /** Starting a Click **/
    function addClick(x, y, dragging) {
        clickX.push(x);
        clickY.push(y);
        clickDrag.push(dragging);
    }

    $('#signaturePad').mousedown(function (e) {
        var mouseX = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var mouseY = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;

        paint = true;
        addClick(e.pageX - this.offsetLeft, e.pageY - this.offsetTop);
        redraw();
    });

});
```

MySQL portion:

```
    <?php
if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
{
$session_id = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
// Get the data
$imageData=$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'];

// Remove the headers (data:,) part.
// A real application should use them according to needs such as to check image type
$filteredData=substr($imageData, strpos($imageData, ",")+1);

// Need to decode before saving since the data we received is already base64 encoded
$unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);

//echo "unencodedData".$unencodedData;
$imageName = "sign_" . rand(5,1000) . rand(1, 10) . rand(10000, 150000) . rand(1500, 100000000) . ".png";
//Set the absolute path to your folder (i.e. /usr/home/your-domain/your-folder/
$filepath = "htdocs/alpha/site6/signature/images/" . $imageName;

$fp = fopen("$filepath", 'wb' );
fwrite( $fp, $unencodedData);
fclose( $fp );

//Connect to a mySQL database and store the user's information so you can link to it later
$link = mysql_connect('localhost','root', 'pwd') OR DIE(mysql_error);
mysql_select_db("trial", $link);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO customer (`session`, `image_location`) VALUES ('$session_id', '$imageName')") OR DIE(mysql_error());
mysql_close($link);
}
?>
```

Comment: There are a lot of things with this code. But for the clear signature, you need to add a handler for the click on the button to actually invoke the clear function. Setting `canvas.width = canvas.width` is a hack and doesn't work in all browsers. Use `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)` instead. The code for saving signature is double up in this code..

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware so if I understand you right, I removed the canvas.width and canvas.heigh and replaced with the ctx.clearRect and I added a handler to the clear button of onClick="clearSig()"  If that's correct it still doesn't clear the canvas. I also removed the second saving signature code but it still wont save to the databse. I'm not sure what to do with this section ajax.open("POST", 'http://www.your-domain.com/folder/post-html.php'); does the post-html.php get changed or stay?

Comment: Ok, I added a partial answer.

Comment: @Ken-AbdiasSoftware so adding ctx.clearRect in place of canvas.width doesn't work either I get a error ctx undefined. I put it back how it was and with the handler assigned to the button it will clear it but as soon as the pointer is placed back on the canvas the previous text reappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only give a partial answer as I cannot help with the PHP part.

I put the code in a jsfiddle with a few corrections here:
http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/M8pzB/

You can see the clear button works as I suggested (except I used ctx in my comment instead of context).

I also removed a double ID'ed div (imgData) from the HTML.

The clear function:

```
$('#clearSig').click(
    function clearSig() {
        clickX = new Array();
        clickY = new Array();
        clickDrag = new Array();
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
});
```

I added a debug tag to the HTML which shows everything now works up to the point where you gonna send it to server. As I cannot test this part I can only suggest you start debug from that part.

I also added URI encoding for the resulting data-url from canvas which is necessary.

The transfer MIME can be `text/plain` instead as what you transfer is a string. Since you use jQuery you can use the built-in function for ajax-transfer:
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

On PHP-side you then decode the URI, strip off header of data-url as you do and then base64 decode it if you want to store it as binary. Note that in MySQL you will then need to store it as a BLOB (not to be confused with HTML5's Blob object).

Comment: Thank you Ken that helps a lot, that fixed my last comment about the previous text reappearing in the canvas after clearing. As for the BlOB I don't want to store the image in the database just the path to the folder it's uploaded to.

Comment: Thanks again Ken, You got a good portion of it fixed. I'm going to check this off as answered and submit a new question for the database part as I can see on clicking the save button that it passes off to the POST portion of the script and gives me a 200 ok code but nothing happens from there so I'm stumped. Thanks again.

Comment: I have an error with this part:

´$("#saveSig").click(function saveSig() {
    //encode URI
    var sigData = encodeURIComponent(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
    $("#imgData").html('Thank you! Your signature was saved');
    var ajax = XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open("POST", 'sig/signature.php');
    ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/upload');
    ajax.send(sigData);
    $('#debug').html(sigData);
});´
with this error "Error: Failed to construct 'XMLHttpRequest': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function."